# Generate an array of natural numbers based on strings length using formula only

Tags: excel, numbers

I want to generate an array of numbers based on the length of a given string. What i mean is that if i have a string "abrt" i want  excel to generate {1,2,3,4} etc. The question is whether it is possible to do that with use of formula only?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
=ROW(INDIRECT("1:"& LEN(A1)))
```

or

```
=ROW(INDEX($A:$A,1):INDEX($A:$A,LEN(A1)))
```

If using an older version of Excel, replace A:A with 1:65535 as full column references may cause a problem

Research volatile formulas to understand a difference between the two formulas.